# React: potential race condition for Controlled Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

There is the following code in [the React tutorial](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components):

```
class NameForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ''};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.value);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
```

There is also [a warning](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) about the *setState* method:

> *setState()* does not always immediately update the component. It may
>   batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading *this.state*
>   right after calling *setState()* a potential pitfall.

**Q:** Is the following scenario possible:

1. *handleChange* is fired;
2. *setState* is queued in the React;
3. *handleSubmit* is fired and it reads an obsolete value of *this.state.value*;
4. *setState* is actually processed.

Or there is some kind of protection preventing such scenario from happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I hope [this](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11171#issuecomment-358329964)
answers your question:

> In React 16, if you call setState inside a React event handler, it is flushed when React exits the browser event handler. So it's not synchronous but happens in the same top-level stack.
>
> In React 16, if you call setState outside a React event handler, it is flushed immediately.

Let's examine what happens (main points):

1. entering `handleChange` react event handler;
2. all `setState` calls are batched inside;
3. exiting `handleChange`
4. flushing `setState` changes
5. `render` is called
6. entering `handleSubmit`
7. accessing correctly commited values from `this.state`
8. exiting `handleSubmit`

So as you see, race condition can't happen as long as updates are scheduled within `React` event handlers, since `React` commits all batched `state` updates in the end of every event handler call.

Answer (score 5):

In your case reading old value is impossible. Under "It may batch or defer the update until later" it means just a case

```
this.setState({a: 11});
console.log(this.state.a);
```

so `setState` may just add a change to queue but not directly update `this.state`. But it does not mean you can just change input with triggering `handleChange` and then click button triggering `handleSubmit` and `.state` is still not updated. It because how [event loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop) works - if some code is executing browser will not process any event(you should experience cases when UI freezes for a while).

So the only thing to reproduce 'race condition' is to run one handler from another:

```
handleChange(event) {
  this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  this.handleSubmit();
}
```

This way, yes, you will get previous `value` shown in alert.

For such a cases [`.setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) takes optional callback parameter

> The second parameter to setState() is an optional callback function that will be executed once setState is completed and the component is re-rendered. Generally we recommend using componentDidUpdate() for such logic instead.

Applied to your code it'd look like

```
handleChange(event) {
  this.setState({value: event.target.value}, this.handleSubmit);
}
```

PS And sure your code may delay `setState` with `setTimeout` on your own like

```
handleChange({target: {value}}) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({value});
    }, 5000);
}
```

And there is no way to ensure `handleSubmit` is operating on latest value. But in such a case it's all on your shoulders how to handle that.

[UPD] some details on how async works in JS. I have heard different terms: "event loop", "message queue", "microtask/task queue" and sometimes it means different things(and there [is a difference](https://jakearchibald.com/2015/tasks-microtasks-queues-and-schedules/) actually). But to make things easier let's assume there is just single queue. And everything async like event handlers, `Promise.then()`, `setImmediate()` just go to the end of this queue.

This way each `setState`(if it's in batch mode) does 2 things: adds changeset to stack(it could be array variable) and set up additional task into queue(say with `setImmediate`). This additional task will process all stacked changes and run rerender just once.

Even if you would be so fast to click Submit button before those deferred updater is executed event handler would go to the end of queue. So event handler will definitely run after all batched state's changes are applied.

Sorry, I cannot just refer to React code to prove because updater code looks really complex for me. But I found [article that has many details](https://reactkungfu.com/2016/03/dive-into-react-codebase-handling-state-changes/#inside_the_react___down_the_rabbit_hole_) how it works under the hood. Maybe it gives some additional information to you.

[UPD] met nice article on microtasks, macrotasks and event loop: https://abc.danch.me/microtasks-macrotasks-more-on-the-event-loop-881557d7af6f?gi=599c66cc504c
it does not change the result but makes me understand all that better

Comment: It became more clear to me, but not crystal yet. Do you say that React queues *setState* calls to some internal JS query that is **guaranteed** to be processed in between handling events?

Comment: after reviewing my own answer I see it looks overcomplicated. So I've updated answer with more details.

Comment: Your and Karen answers are both great and I was having a hard time deciding whom to award the bounty. I have accepted Karen's answer for being more concise. But bounty goes to your answer as being much more detailed and containing useful references to investigate this issue in depth.

Comment: found good article on microtask/macrotask/event loop: https://abc.danch.me/microtasks-macrotasks-more-on-the-event-loop-881557d7af6f?gi=599c66cc504c